# Jquery cycle2 video js plugin does not work for Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, drupal, drupal-7

I have video slider and wen I started video on the one slide and then change it to the another slide previous video does not stop. 
My js options

```
this.speed = 1000;
this.timeout = 0;

this.slider = $('.cycle-slideshow');

  this.slider.cycle({
  slides: '.slide',
  fx: 'scrollHorz',
  swipe: true,
  timeout: this.timeout,
  speed: this.speed,
  next: '.tagg-video-slider .cycle-next',
  prev: '.tagg-video-slider .cycle-prev',
  youtube: true,
  youtubeAutostart: true
});
```

structure of my slide :

```
<iframe class="media-youtube-player" width="640" height="390" title="zSm91-i_h6Y" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/zSm91-i_h6Y?wmode=opaque&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=media-youtube-zsm91-i-h6y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" style="visibility: hidden;">Video of zSm91-i_h6Y</iframe>
```

Is it problem with iframe or what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this module
[jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update)

Comment: Thanks but I've fixed this with iframe[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'pauseVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');